# How to evaluate $\int \frac{\log x}{x^2}$?

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

I want to know how to evaluate $\int \frac{\log x}{x^2}$.
Using by parts, and after moving terms, we get something like
$$2 \int\frac{\log x}{x^2} = \frac{(\log x)^2}{x} + \int \frac{(\log x)^2}{x^2}$$
Using by parts again gives
$$\int \frac{(\log x)^2}{x^2} = \frac{2}{3}(\log x)^3 - \int \frac{(\log x)^3}{x^2}$$
At this point, I give up, since it looks like this is leading to nowhere.

Wxmaxima suggests the answer should be $-\frac{\log x}{x} - \frac{1}{x}$ but I can neither derive it nor find it on the Internet. Thank for your help!

Comment: Oh, I feel silly now. I should have note $(-\frac{1}{x})' = \frac{1}{x^2}$. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\int\frac{\ln x}{x^2}dx$$
$$\int(\ln x) \frac{1}{x^2}dx$$
$$\ln x. (\frac{-1}{x})+\int\frac{1}{x^2}dx$$
$$\frac{-\ln x}{x^2}-\frac{1}{x}+C$$

Answer (score 3):

Well, using integration by parts:

$$\int\frac{\ln\left(x\right)}{x^2}\space\text{d}x=-\frac{\ln\left(x\right)}{x}+\int\frac{1}{x^2}\space\text{d}x\tag1$$

Answer (score 2):

Use $$u=\log(x)\implies u'=\frac{dx}x$$ $$v'=\frac {dx}{x^2}\implies v=-\frac 1x$$